# How to create and show Popup from code in Avalonia

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

From XAML i'm created Popup, but i need create him from code.
My code:

```
    var popup = new Popup()
    {
        IsVisible = true,
        IsOpen = true,
        PlacementRect = new(50, 50, 100, 75),
        Child = new Border {
            BorderThickness = new(0.75),
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
            Padding = new(6, 3),
            Child = new TextBlock
            {
                Background = Brushes.White,
                Text = textContent
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Popup won't work without a parent window.

Comment: Thanks, but with `this.VisualChildren.Add(popup);` still not working

Comment: Maybe really create him in XAML and change text content and visibility every call

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Create a Custom Presenter

This one is the container for our data.

**CustomPresenter.cs**

```
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls.Primitives;

namespace AvaloniaPopup.Views
{
    public class CustomPresenter : PickerPresenterBase
    {
        public string Text
        {
            get => GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly StyledProperty<string> TextProperty =
            AvaloniaProperty.Register<CustomPresenter, string>(nameof(Text));
    }
}
```

#### 2. Add a template for our Popup in the hosting window

**MainWindow.axaml**

```
<Window.Styles>
    <Style Selector="v|CustomPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="0.75"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    Padding="6,3"
                    Background="White">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Styles>
```

**Important:** Don't forget to declare the namespace in the window

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:AvaloniaPopup.Views;assembly=AvaloniaPopup">
```

#### 3. Put the Popup and Presenter in AXAML code of the Window

**MainWindow.axaml**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<Button Content="Show Popup" Name="popupButton" Click="OnPopupButton_Click" />
<Popup Name="Popup"
    WindowManagerAddShadowHint="False"
    StaysOpen="False"
    PlacementMode="Bottom"
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=popupButton}">
<v:CustomPresenter />
</Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

#### 4. Create code-behind Click method to open Popup

**MainWindow.axaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Popup popup;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        popup = this.FindControl<Popup>("Popup");
    }

    private void OnPopupButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (popup.IsOpen)
        {
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
        else
        {
            popup.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```